# How to fix CA Dispose objects before losing scope?

Tags: c#

CA throw the following message:

```
CA2000 Dispose objects before losing scope.
In method 'GetMatchingJobsDeferred(BackgroundJobSearchParameters)',
object '<>g__initLocal0' is not disposed along all exception paths.
Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object '<>g__initLocal0' before 
all references to it are out of scope.
```

I have disposable type `CompositeCollection`.

```
public sealed class CompositeCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IEnumerable<T>> _enumerables = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
    private readonly List<IDisposable> _disposables = new List<IDisposable>();

    public void Add(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerables.Add(enumerable);
    }

    public void Add(IDeferredResultCollection<T> deferredResultCollection)
    {
        _enumerables.Add(deferredResultCollection);
        _disposables.Add(deferredResultCollection);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerables.Aggregate((results, enumerable) => results.Concat(enumerable)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var item in _disposables)
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And that how I used it:

```
public IDeferredResultCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight> GetMatchingJobsDeferred(BackgroundJobSearchParameters jobSearchParameters)
{
    var memoryLocatedJobs = GetInMemoryJobs(jobSearchParameters);
    var databaseLocatedJobs = GetInDatabaseJobsDeferred(jobSearchParameters, memoryLocatedJobs);

    return new CompositeCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight>
    {
        memoryLocatedJobs,
        databaseLocatedJobs
    };
}
```

I have exception when `return` statement called.
How to fix that?

I add `try catch` and it doesn't help

```
 public IDeferredResultCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight> GetMatchingJobsDeferred(BackgroundJobSearchParameters jobSearchParameters)
    {
        CompositeCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight> deferredJobs = null;
        DeferredResultCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight> databaseLocatedJobs = null;
        try
        {
            var memoryLocatedJobs = GetInMemoryJobs(jobSearchParameters);
            databaseLocatedJobs = GetInDatabaseJobsDeferred(jobSearchParameters, memoryLocatedJobs);

            deferredJobs = new CompositeCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight> { memoryLocatedJobs, databaseLocatedJobs };
            return deferredJobs;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (databaseLocatedJobs != null)
            {
                databaseLocatedJobs.Dispose();
            }

            if (deferredJobs != null)
            {
                deferredJobs.Dispose();
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I honestly think this is a bug with CA2000: it doesn't deal with disposable objects leaving method scope and therefore I suppress it in those cases.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson ok, thanks. Can you please recommend me a books to read about performance in .net?

Comment: Try renaming the method to `Create...` instead of `Get...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When returning the disposable objects, it should be the responsibility of the caller code to `Dispose` the object. Had the `Disposed` been called inside the method itself, the disposed object will return to the caller method, (*wont be of any use*).

In that case it is safe to supress the warning.

BUT what if the exception occurred in this method?

> If a disposable object is not explicitly disposed before all
>   references to it are out of scope, the object will be disposed at some
>   indeterminate time when the garbage collector runs the finalizer of
>   the object. Because an exceptional event might occur that will prevent
>   the finalizer of the object from running, the object should be
>   explicitly disposed instead. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx)

So, if you anticipate any exception in the method, you should have this code in `try...catch` block and in `catch` block you should call `Dispose()` checking if the object is not null.

And when you are not returning `IDisposable` you can use `using` statement or `try...finally` and call dispose in `finally`

Comment: I would like to call this method in the another method, like this

`using(var a = myclass.GetMatchingJobsDeferred()) {...}`

Comment: @Anatoly In your method, if there are possibility of exception while creating the `CompositeCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight>` object and `memoryLocatedJobs` and `databaseLocatedJobs`, you can have a `try...catch` block and inside `catch` block, you can call `dispose()` checking if the `CompositeCollection<BackgroundJobInfoLight>` is not null. And your implementation is correct in the caller method.

Comment: I added `try...catch` and it doesnt help

Comment: `memoryLocatedJobs ` its just a List

Comment: @Anatoly - `try...catch` will still show the warning, because the code analysis tool is not aware about how you've implemented your solution. `try...catch` block will make sure that even if there is any exception, your object is properly `disposed`, so after doing this can safely supress the waring. No worries. :)

Comment: @Anatoly - As per your edited code, in `catch` you just need to Dispose `deferredJobs` only as you are returning this. If `databaseLocatedJobs` is also IDisposable, you should use `using` statement on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping items in to different list variables? It may have something to do with your issue.  Keep it [DRY](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) Store them in one list and safely cast to what you are looking for.

```
IDisposable myDispType = myEnumarableType as IDisposable;
If (myDispType != null)
    {//your logic here}
```